# Add the effective pom.xml in the META-INF directory

Tags: maven-2

When I build a JAR library using Maven 2 (version `2.0.9` or `2.2.1`), the `pom.xml` of the library is copied in the `META-INF/maven/[groupId]/[artifactId]/` directory of the JAR.

However, in my case, the `pom.xml` has a parent, and I would prefer to get the [effective-pom](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html) instead of the original `pom.xml` file (or eventually, having both of them).

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate the effective-pom.xml during install cycle

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.1</version>
     <executions>
        <execution>
           <phase>generate-resources</phase>
       <goals>
          <goal>effective-pom</goal>
       </goals>
       <configuration>
          <output>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/maven/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/effective-pom.xml</output>
       </configuration>
      </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

<s>But to copy this effective-pom.xml to under `META-INF/maven/[groupId]/[artifactId]/` directory of the JAR file, you will have to write a custom Jar mojo (just by extending `org.apache.maven.plugin.jar.JarMojo`) because the code that copies the `pom.xml` to META-INF is hard-coded in [org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver][1] (Line 487) (and i think there is no apparent way to set/override this behavior from pom.xml).</s>

**Update**: Thanks to @RomainLinsolas it is possible to directly put the pom there. Updated the solution

Comment: Thanks. Note that if you configure this plugin with `<output>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/maven/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/effective-pom.xml</output>`, then the `effective-pom.xml` will be put on the correct place in the JAR!

Comment: @romaintaz +1 Thanks for providing the info about <output>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/maven/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/effective-pom.xml</output>.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use https://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/

It will set updatePomFile true by default.

Its not what you asked for, but its what you want.