# How to get the path of the pom file in a maven war project

Tags: java, maven

hi is there a way to get the path of pom file in a maven project.
i need to read pom file and use it to get some information like version, list of dependencies and so on ..

```
 MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
          Model model = reader.read(MainTest.class.getResourceAsStream( "how to get this path"+"/pom.xml"));
          for(Dependency d : model.getDependencies())
          {
              System.out.println(d.getArtifactId());
          }
```

Comment: Can you explain in which relationship you need to read them? During a Jenkins build?

Comment: no. i know that using jenkins api i can got those information and i use it already. my case that at runtime in the application i want to display the dependencies  tree in a web page

Comment: Why not let Maven create a file which contains this information during the build and just display it during runtime..for example via [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) and package the resulting file into the war/jar ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to copy the effective pom to META-INF folder. Check this link [Add the effective pom.xml in the META-INF directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254812/add-the-effective-pom-xml-in-the-meta-inf-directory)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the pom to the META-INF folder as suggested above.  You can also use the pom.properties file that the Jar and related Maven archive plugins put in META-INF by default.  In either case, you can then access it as a resource provided that the jar is in the classpath. The only example I have of this is written in Groovy:

```
def static String getMavenVersion(Class mainClass) {
    //
    // If this doesn't work, the likely reason is that we're running in development, so start with a
    // reasonable default
    //
    def String result = "Lastest Development"

    //
    // Get our package - one up in the tree is the path to the properties file we want.
    //
    def String packagePath = mainClass.package.name
    def int index = packagePath.lastIndexOf(".")
    def String groupId = packagePath.substring(0, index)
    def String artifact = packagePath.substring(index + 1)


    //
    // Get the version from the property file
    //
    Protect.resource
    {
        InputStream input = MiscUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/maven/${groupId}/${artifact}/pom.properties")
        input
    }
    { InputStream input ->
        if (input != null) {
            def Properties mavenProps = new Properties()
            mavenProps.load(input)
            result = mavenProps.getAt("version")
        }
    }

    result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
example; 
 ı_____project files(pom.xml in this files) 
  I_____src 
   I____main 
    ı____java 
      ı___com 
       ı___file 
        ı___file2 
         ı___ my class

your be if class hierarchy;

 ....../pom.xml 
or
 ./../../../../../pom.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

In maven project, project directory has pom.xml.
`System.getProperty("user.dir")` gives project directory.
Try -
`Model model = reader.read(MainTest.class.getResourceAsStream( System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/pom.xml"));`